# Open link in new window without window.opener reference

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some issues with the window system in Javascript:

I have a website A that lists links to a different website B (currently `<a>` tags with `target="_blank"` attributes).

I would like the link in A to open in a new tab from B, however the page from B (**which I cannot edit**) contains a script that changes the location of the `window.parent`, in this case the tab containing the website A, then closes itself.

So I'm looking for a way to open a new tab/window without a reference to the current page in `window.{parent/top/opener}`. Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you mean a thrd party page loads a new page on an existing tab? That shouldn't be even possible. Also, tabs/windows don't have `window.parent` it is a property of (i)frames. There's `window.opener`, but that should be `null` if the domains are not the same ... [Not in all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener), I can see. You could try the `rel` attribute as the docs is talking about.

Comment: Yep sorry I mixed up the two, it's the `window.opener` reference I was trying to remove. Anyway I found a way to do that using a short function that opens the new window and immediately set its opener to `null`. (I tested your rel="noopener" solution but as the doc says it's not available in all browsers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to remove the `window.opener` reference to my site, so if anyone encounters the same kind of problem here is a solution:

```html
<a href="javascript:openLink('http://example.com')">Link</a>
```

```js
var openLink = function(url) {
  var w = window.open(url, '_blank');
  w.opener = null;
}
```

Comment: You can make it a single line like `window.open(url, '_blank').opener=null;`  for inline functions.

Answer (score 1):

Add the `rel="noopener"` attribute to the anchor tag:

```
<a target="_blank" rel="noopener" href="http://example.com">Link</a>
```

This is supported in most browsers: https://caniuse.com/#search=noopener

Notes:

- IE and Edge don't support `rel="noopener"`, but they also don't set `window.opener` for cross-origin links (I can't find an authoritative reference for this, however).
- If you need to support other browsers (i.e. Safari 10 or others) that *do* set `window.opener` and don't support `rel="noopener"`, @Elassyo's technique will work.